# Post-Redirect-Get in perl cgi file

Tags: perl, http, redirect, cgi

I have a server that uses local file system that look like this

Main Folder --

Search.cgi (contain 2 forms, 1 is search and display record.txt, another to update the respective record.txt)

Person 1 folder -

Person 1 update.cgi

Person 1 record.txt

Person 2 folder -

Person 2 update.cgi

Person 2 record.txt

Right now search.cgi is able to update individual record 1 at a time and directing to update.cgi which will display the outcome of the update. However users find it tedious as they need to go back every time if they need to update multiple entry. Is there a way to update the record.txt and redirect back to search.cgi with the previous search input?

In search.cgi

```
<FORM action="search.cgi" method="post" name="search">
```

In search.cgi, for each record:

```
 <form id="Form" action="$formLocation/update.cgi" method="post" target=_self>
 <td><input id="submit"  type=submit name=submit value=Update  target="_blank" size="2">&nbsp;</td>
```

In update.cgi, it will process the form input and print qq?

```
            <Tr><td><U>UPDATED</U><td></Tr> 
            <Tr><BR><td>Ref No                  : $Ref_no</td></Tr>
            <Tr><td>ID                          : $loginid </td></Tr>
            <Tr><td>Name                        : $loginname</td></Tr>
            <Tr><td>Acknowledment               : $ack </td></Tr>
            <Tr><td>Date and Time               : $subdate</td></Tr>
            <BR>    <TR><TD align=center><a href=$ROOTLINK target=_parent><font color=navy><b>Logout</b></font></a></td></tr>
```

?;

UPDATES

I decided to use hidden input to pass the search input from search.cgi to update.cgi and redirect the search input using a URL query. right now I am using a meta tag but I am having problem with the syntax as I am unable to include the URL into the meta tag. Is it possible to do so ? I keep getting the $URL in my browser URL instead of the actual URL.

```
    $url = 'http://example.com/search.cgi?search1=$input1&search2=$input2';
    print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=$url">';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to really understand what you're asking, but I suspect the answer will involve cookies.

- In `search.cgi`, see if there's a cookie set, then use that to pre-populate the search box.
- When you receive a request with a search term, then use that to set the search cookie value.
- At the end of `update.cgi` return a response that redirects the browser to `search.cgi`.

But, all in all, I think you would really benefit from rewriting this as a real web application using a framework like [Dancer2](https://perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](https://www.mojolicious.org/).

**Update:**

Looking at your updated suggestion, I have three comments:

- I think using cookies is a cleaner solution than using hidden fields
- The reason that the URL is not ending up in your header is that you are printing a single-quoted string - and variables aren't expanded in single-quoted strings. You'll need to change that to a double-quoted string.
- If you're using CGI.pm (and you really should be) then don't create your own redirection header. Use the `redirect()` function instead (see [Generating a redirection header](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Generating-a-redirection-header)).

Comment: Sorry I am having a lot of restriction from the company which prevent me from using framework and drastic change on the application. Can you take a look at my new proposed solution and see if it can work ? Cause if I am able to fix that issue, my supervisor will be contented enough

Comment: @huangyanping: See the update in my answer.